# GET request cuts request of URL in half PHP

Tags: php, url, get, http-redirect

I am trying to make a GET request but when I try to pick up the url it cuts it in half like this:

This is the request

```
http://mydomain.dev/getdata?id=22232&t=1&url=http://www.example.com/Public/AView.aspx?RemoteId=3CB0CDA14-C8BC-44E3-A1B1-8E389ER3B07&PublisherG=ed4fe6d2-4543-42d4-a51c-c1cfcbcc1b3a
```

And here is what i get if i echo Input::get('url');

```
http://www.example.com/Public/AView.aspx?RemoteId=3CB0CDA14-C8BC-44E3-A1B1-8E389ER3B07
```

Why is this?

If it's to any help i'm using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Input::get('url');` should be exactly what you're getting back.   It's returning the value the parameter literally named `url` in the get request.  `Input::get()` return get params.

If you want the actual URI for the request made, you need the request object: https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests

Also, you need to `urlencode()` the url you're passing as a get parameter.

```
$url_param = urlencode("http://www.example.com/Public/AView.aspx?RemoteId=3CB0CDA14-C8BC-44E3-A1B1-8E389ER3B07&PublisherG=ed4fe6d2-4543-42d4-a51c-c1cfcbcc1b3a");

$final_url = "http://mydomain.dev/getdata?id=22232&t=1&url=".$url_param;
```

Comment: Great it worked! YOu know how to do the same in Javascript?

Comment: If your generating manually the full url string in javascript I think you'd want `encodeURI()` on the parameter value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript